# Getting 500 for get_account_tree call in box API

Tags: box-api

I am getting 500 http status code for few user when i am making **get_account_tree** call.

For only one user I am getting application_restricted, how can this be possible? all other users are working fine.

I am making a curl call like this:

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?\
action=get_account_tree&api_key=XXXXXX&auth_token=XXXXX\
&par‌​ams[]=nofiles&folder_id=0
```

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error

Comment: i am making a curl call to box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_account_tree&api_key=XXXXXX&auth_token=XXXXX&params[]=nofiles&folder_id=0 and this is happening to a very few users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated [in the documentation](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923929/ApiFunction_get_account_tree), it's strongly recommended that you use the `onelevel` parameter because some Box accounts may be thousands of folders deep, in which case the call will not return. If you add this parameter to your get_account_tree calls, it should work without 500-ing.